# Forms Data Manipulation Revise

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms, formulas

I came across this post that is doing exactly what I want.

We use a Google form to collect new learners to add to a store.
What I'm trying to do is have the first 9 columns repeat for each learner, with each learner going onto a new line. Again this [link](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/88736/forms-data-manipulation-in-google-sheets/114304#114304) shows it exactly.

I modified this with my own data and it works, EXCEPT it seemingly adds additional lines when no users are left. Anyone have an idea as to why I'm getting extra lines?
A link to my working file:
[<strike>https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14e6bbRDrUCE1XidTfnITvhXMpUpfiDDebyV8DSWBaFI/edit?usp=sharing</strike>](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14e6bbRDrUCE1XidTfnITvhXMpUpfiDDebyV8DSWBaFI/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

The formulas that you use add a row for each "learner" question even if they haven't answers.

The easier solution is to use the filter feature to hide the rows having blank "learner" data blank.

Other alternatives are the use of built-in functions like QUERY and FILTER.

Comment: Hey Ruben, You are absolutely right. Is there any way to automate through a formulate, any rows that don't have learner data?

Comment: @JamesLavis: I updated my answer. For further details, please follow the [tour] and checkout [ask] to learn the ropes about asking question on this site.

Comment: Hey Ruben, while I appreciate the support you provide, I was merely posing a clarification question. I'm sure these boards have a ridiculous amount of newbie posts, but at this point in the digital age, many folks belong to 10+ communities. Referring users to those links won't accomplish what you want.

Comment: @JamesLavis: Thanks for the clarification about the clarification and the feedback :)