# Google Sheets split into new rows while duplicating surrounding row entries

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am creating a spreadsheet for a service drive my non-profit is doing. As people sign up through a Google Form, the information comes in like this:

[image: Undivided]

However, to make it easier on our volunteers, it would be beneficial to have the information split up into a smaller pieces and be more uniform.

I need a way for the sheet to do the following:

1. A way to copy the Parent's First and last name, as well as their Phone Number and Building Pickup number (I.e. Columns A-D), while giving a separate row for each of their children (+their needs on the same row.)
2. A process that can handle a variable amount of children
3. An **automated** process of handling this information.

The sheet should look like this:
[image: divided]

I would greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: Welcome Jacob. Please have a look at this [simple solution](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/129650/117311)  which exactly addresses your problem. If still in need let me know.

Comment: Thank you marikamitsos! That answered my question completely.

Comment: Although one would think I tend to be biased, I believe it is the best solution.  Glad I could help :)